# Are CNG classes in .NET Cryptography namespace FIPS certified?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cryptographic-services:

> Managed code wrappers for the Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS) certified implementations of the AES, SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512 implementations are available in the new AesCryptoServiceProvider, SHA256CryptoServiceProvider, SHA384CryptoServiceProvider, and SHA512CryptoServiceProvider classes.

Does this mean that CNG classes are not FIPS certified? I'm asking this because sometimes the docs lack information (for example Public Key Encryption section doesn't even mention CNG implementation)

EDIT:

> The Cryptography Next Generation (CNG) classes provide a managed
>   wrapper around the native CNG functions.

So CNG is a managed code wrapper, thus confirming my initial guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "managed wrapper" just means "is a C# API that takes care of calling the CNG C API".  The cryptography is provided by a FIPS Certified library (provided that the OS is configured to be in the mode under which the library got certified).  It's the same statement used for the CAPI versions `Managed code wrappers for ...`.

So, they're exactly as certified as the *CryptoServiceProvider types, in that they're not directly certified, but they're also not doing the cryptographic operations themselves.